# Keras model.predict error for categorical labels

Tags: python, numpy, keras, label, prediction

I am trying to see prediction results and print them with model.predict function but I am having an error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model : the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[array([   0,....
```

I have multiple input, both are embedded. This code was previously working when I have one input as embedded.

```
for i in range(100):
    prediction_result = model.predict(np.array([test_text[i], test_posts[i]]))
    predicted_label = labels_name[np.argmax(prediction_result)]
    print(text_data.iloc[i][:100], "")
    print('Actual label:' + tags_test.iloc[i])
    print("Predicted label: " + predicted_label + "\n")
```

test_text and test_posts are the result of pad_sequences. They are in array, test_text has shape of 100 and test_posts has shape of 1. labels_name is names of the labels. I am having error in the second line;

```
prediction_result = model.predict(np.array([test_text[i], test_posts[i]]))
```

Error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps)
   1815         x = _standardize_input_data(x, self._feed_input_names,
   1816                                     self._feed_input_shapes,
-> 1817                                     check_batch_axis=False)
   1818         if self.stateful:
   1819             if x[0].shape[0] > batch_size and x[0].shape[0] % batch_size != 0:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
     84                 'Expected to see ' + str(len(names)) + ' array(s), '
     85                 'but instead got the following list of ' +
---> 86                 str(len(data)) + ' arrays: ' + str(data)[:200] + '...')
     87         elif len(names) > 1:
     88             raise ValueError(

ValueError: Error when checking model : the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[array([   0,    0,  ...
```

It looks like a simple solution but I couldn't find it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model expects two arrays and you are passing one single numpy array.

```
 prediction_result = model.predict([test_text.values[i].reshape(-1,100), test_posts.values[i].reshape(-1,1)])
```

remove calling the numpy.array method and you the Error will go away.

Update:
There is no need to use `for loop`.

```
prediction_result = model.predict([test_text.values.reshape(-1,100), test_posts.values.reshape(-1,1)])
```

This can do what you want. prediction_result is now have shape of `(number rows in test_text,number of outputs)`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I am having this error though;
ValueError: Error when checking : expected input_text to have shape (100,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: can you show me the result of
`print model.inputs[0].shape` and
`print model.inputs[1].shape`

Comment: (?, 100) (?, 1) These are the results respectively.

Comment: what about `test_text.values.shape` and `test_posts.values.shape`?

Comment: (6255, 100) (6255, 1) These are the results respectively. These are the just shape results if I add values, I am having an error AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: I've updated the code. But I'm not sure why you are iterating 100 times over test data.

Comment: Thank you it worked. I am not sure but I don't iterate 100 times on purpose. 100 is the either embedding dimension or sequence length for text data.

Comment: Why do you think so? As I said when I used only test_text with the shape of  (6255, 100), it worked. There was no error.